# chef client 12.4.0 and recipe with version

Tags: chef-infra

The command chef-client -o 'recipe[cookbook::recipe@version]' works on Chef Client version 11.12.2 but does not work on version 12.4.0

Any pointers please.

Comment: And what error did you get? Additionally why are you trying to run this command anyway? The run-list is normally set on bootstrap. Are you attempting to run chef in local mode, in which case you need to include the "-z" option?

Comment: Thank you Mark. There is no error just that it says recipe cookbook::recipe@version not found. I need to run this command on a need basis (e.g. test). We are using the run list and this is run against the server. I was wondering whether there is a change in format! For now I might use the run list and set the recipe version on the node.

Comment: ok.... So is the desired version of your cookbook actually loaded into the chef server? If not that would explain the "version not found" message.

Comment: Yes it is. If I downgrade the chef-client version the same command works. So I am guessing two issues. Either - chef-client 12 have issue talking to old version of chef for recipes with version or - the structure for calling recipe with verison has changed